# Prepend only 4 items to each column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have three columns in my html to which I'd like to prepend some sections using Javascript(snippet isn't going to work here because of missing dependencies):

```js
function createUserSection(ticket) {
  panel = $('div[user="' + ticket.Operator + '"]');

  if (!panel[0]) {
    html = "<section class=\"panel\">" +
      "<header class=\"panel-heading\">" +
      ticket.Operator +
      "</header>" +
      "<div class=\"panel-body user-panel\" max-items=\"100\" user=\"" + ticket.Operator + "\"></div>" +
      "</section>";

    column = $('#users');
    columnTwo = $('#users2');
    columnThree = $('#users3');
    column.prepend(html);
    columnTwo.prepend(html);
    columnThree.prepend(html);
  }

  panel = $('div[user="' + ticket.Operator + '"]');
  return panel;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-order " id="users" max-items="1000"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-order " id="users2" max-items="1000"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel-order " id="users3" max-items="1000"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This kinda does what I want, however, it fills all 3 columns with the same(all) ticket operators like this: 
[image]

What I want is the following:

[image]

So I'd like to have max 4 per column, only filling the next column if the current one is full. Is this possible? I'm quite new to programming, I've tried for several hours, but I can't make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document.  You're adding multple `<row><div id="users"` so when you do `$("#users")` it either does the first one only or all of them.  Use a class instead

Comment: I have #users, #users2, and #users3. Those are 3 unique ID's. It does what I want, I just need a way to filter it so I only have 4 users per column, instead of all users in every column (the number of users is dynamic).

Comment: Ok, it's not clear from the small sample